# How to animate every element in equal speed in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have simple animation.

```
$(element).animate({
    left: rand_value() + "px"
}, 5000, "linear");
```

But there is one little-big problem. Animation duration is 5 seconds from point A to point B. But I want to animate every element with equal speed from point A to point B without dependences from time. And I don't know how to do this.

Example:

- ElemA: start point is 0, end point is 1000
- ElemB: srart point is 0, end point is 200

Speed of ElemA and ElemB must be equal, ~ 10px/second. And it means that the animation is different duration.

Comment: linear should be animating at same interval of time, can you show us a demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
var rand = rand_value();
$(element).animate({
    left: rand + "px"
}, 100*rand, "linear");
```

Here's why this makes sense: `speed = distance/time`, so `10px/sec = rand/time` and thus `0.01px/millisecond = rand/time` such that `time = rand/0.01` which is equal to `time = rand * 100`. This is consistent with the fact that `.animate(...)` takes a duration in millisecond units.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thank you for your idea **JCOC611**
There is suitable solution, for me

```
var rand = rand_value();
var multiplier = 3; // multiplier, to decrease animation speed
$(element).animate({
    left:  rand +"px)"
}, rand * multiplier, "linear");
```

In this way, every animation will be with equal speed, and it speed can be controlled with multiplier.